# Docker Check if DB is Running

Tags: bash, docker, cassandra

`entrypoint.sh` contains various cqlsh commands that require Cassandra. Without something like `script.sh`, cqlsh commands fail because Cassandra doesn't have enough time to start. When I execute the following locally, everything appears to work properly. However, when I run via Docker, `script.sh` never finishes. In other words, `$status` never changes from 1 to 0.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM cassandra
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y netcat
RUN mkdir /dir
ADD ./scripts /dir/scripts
RUN /bin/bash -c 'service cassandra start'
RUN /bin/bash -c '/dir/scripts/script.sh'
RUN /bin/bash -c '/dir/scripts/entrypoint.sh'
```

**script.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
cmd="$@"

status=$(nc -z localhost 9042; echo $?)
echo $status

while [ $status != 0 ]
do
  sleep 3s
  status=$(nc -z localhost 9042; echo $?)
  echo $status
done

exec $cmd
```

Alternatively, I could do something like `until cqlsh -e 'some code'; do ..`, as noted [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) for psql, but that doesn't appear to work for me. Wondering how best to approach the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're misusing the `RUN` command in your Dockerfile. It's not for starting services, it's for making filesystem changes in your image. The reason `$status` doesn't update is because you can't start Cassandra via a `RUN` command.

You should add `service cassandra start` and `/dir/scripts/entrypoint.sh` to your `script.sh` file, and make that the `CMD` that's executed by default:

**Dockerfile**

```
CMD ['/bin/bash', '-c', '/dir/scripts/script.sh']
```

**script.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
# NOTE: I removed your `cmd` processing in favor of invoking entrypoint.sh
# directly.

# Start Cassandra before waiting for it to boot.
service cassandra start

status=$(nc -z localhost 9042; echo $?)
echo $status

while [ $status != 0 ]
do
  sleep 3s
  status=$(nc -z localhost 9042; echo $?)
  echo $status
done

exec /bin/bash -c /dir/scripts/entrypoint.sh
```